# Playwright error "no tests found" when executing via terminal

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I am very new to the whole automation topic so please be so kind and try to be patient with me. Of course I investigated several hours into this topic before even asking, but I just don't understand the problem.

Microsoft VS --> Playwright --> execution inside the example.spec.ts file works, but if I want to do it from the terminal via "npx playwright test" I always get "Error: No tests found".

Even if I try it with the exact path tests/example.spec.js .

```
Error: Playwright Test did not expect test.describe() to be called here.
Most common reasons include:
- You are calling test.describe() in a configuration file.
- You are calling test.describe() in a file that is imported by the configuration file.
- You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens
  when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.

   at example.spec.js:7

   5 | // 2. Group tests together using a describe block
   6 | test.describe('IMDB:', () => {
>  7 |   // 3. Use test block to define executable code necessary to implement the test
     |            ^
   8 |   // 4. Here is a '{ page }' that the test above has access to
   9 |   test('verify search functionality', async ({ page }) => {
  10 |     // 5. Define test data

    at TestTypeImpl._currentSuite (/Users/myname/Desktop/TS:Playwright:Cucumber/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/common/testType.js:69:13)
    at TestTypeImpl._describe (/Users/myname/Desktop/TS:Playwright:Cucumber/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/common/testType.js:87:24)
    at Function.describe (/Users/myname/Desktop/TS:Playwright:Cucumber/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/transform/transform.js:235:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Desktop/TS:Playwright:Cucumber/tests/example.spec.js:7:12)

Error: No tests found
```

This is my config file:

```
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Chrome Stable',
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        channel: 'chrome',
      },
    },
  ],
};

export default config;
```

Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve it?

- Microsoft VS is up to date
- Closed and reopened VS after playwright installation
- Deleted the whole project folder and created again with fresh playwright installation several times
- Tried to insert testDir: '/Users/myname/Desktop/TS:Playwright:Cucumber' into the config file, also didn't help

Example of a feature/scenario:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

test.describe('Login:', () => {

test('verify successful login functionality', async ({}) => {
    
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('xxx');
    await page.getByRole('banner').getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' }).click();
    await page.getByLabel('Username').click();
    await page.getByLabel('Username').fill('xxx');
    await page.getByLabel('Password').click();
    await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('xxxx');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Log In' }).click({ force: true });

    // 8. Assert search result
    expect(await page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Multi-factor authentication' })).toBeVisible;
    browser.close();
  });
});
```

[File hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1HAo.png)

Comment: Is `example.spec.js` a test file that you haven't shown? If so, please share it, along with the paths and contents of all of your files in the project and your package.json. The first step is to ensure all 3 of the suggestions in "Most common reasons include:" are false for your case. Very likely, one of those 3 things applies to your case and it's a matter of figuring out which. But as the question stands, there aren't enough details to make that determination.

Comment: Hey @ggorlen, thanks for your reply, much appreciated!

Unfortunately I can not share my test scenario (example.spec.ts) because there are too many characters for this comment box :/ My package.json though is possible: `{
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.37.1",
    "playwright": "^1.37.1"
  },
  "scripts": {}
}`

Comment: Please create a [mcve] as an [edit] to your post. Thanks. Based on your package.json alone, do you need to have playwright in there? I would try it with just `@playwright/test`, at least temporarily, to help ensure suggestion #3 doesn't apply. You might try removing node_modules and reinstalling everything fresh, in case it's out of sync with the package.json, again looking to see if #3 applies.

Comment: @ggorlen I edited now my post, thanks for this hint! I think I need playwright yes because of the browser.close() command afaik.

I did install everything fresh from scratch already multiple times, unfortunately it didnt help.

Comment: I mean I deleted the project folder and installed Playwright from scratch multiple times - but I didnt try to do it with MS VS as a whole, maybe I have to try this.

Comment: I'm able to run the tests fine with your code and package.json. Are you sure you're running `npx playwright test` in the root directory of the project where the tests are? `@playwright/test` has playwright-core as a dependency, which includes the browser API,  so there should be no need for the playwright package for anything you're doing. But the extra package is probably not the problem.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for checking with the execution - so its definitely nothing related to my project folder but probably something else... yes I definitely execute the command while being in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the config file, you need to define the path for your tests. And should be specified under 'testDir:'. This path should be relative to this configuration file.

Refer to the below playwright documentation:
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration

Comment: Hey @Rudra, thanks for your input!

I tried it with:

```import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Chrome Stable',
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        channel: 'chrome',
        permissions: ['geolocation'],
        geolocation: { latitude: 48.209078, longitude: 16.367240 },
      },
      testDir: 'tests',
    },
  ],
};

export default config;```

and even with the direct path while executing with npx playwright ... but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @ggorlen and @Rudra,

thanks to both of you for your help, I solved the issue and I somehow smelled it...

I searched for all playwright files on my machine via "sudo find / -name playwright" and deleted **everything**. I had some previous playwright installations with Python.

After I deleted everything, I did a very fresh installation with MS VS and now I can execute it via npx playwright test! :)

Have a nice day!